# How to print with thermal printer built-in with EDC machine with kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform, android-print-framework, android-print-manager

I have an EDC machine android and built-in with thermal printer. now i'am make an POS application with jetpack compose kotlin. How can I detect the thermal printer in this EDC machine and how I can print the jetpack compose view? Please help me guys... thankyouu

I have try with this lib.

implementation "com.epson.epos2:epos2-print:1.1.0"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.2"

and when I call
Epos2.newInstance(context)
the Epos2 import doesn't showed and that give me unresolved
reference: Epos2